# Can GitHub classify as a version control system or a GUI for Git?

Tags: git, github

I do get how GitHub is a cloud hosting server for repositories or Git, but it does have some basic functionalities like to add or commit to repositories like Git does without having to download Git. So would that classify it as a version control system, too, or more of a GUI masking the commands with simple button clicks?

Comment: Neither (IMO). GitHub is a git repository hosting site. It has issue tracking, pull request merging, and more. It’s not a GUI like GitKraken, ungit, or git-gui.